# A second micropost feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I finished the Michael hartl Ruby tutorial on Ruby on Rails.
And i'm trying to make a second feed next to it showing the next page of microposts.
But I tried copying the first feed and then put it next to my original feed.
Now i have 2 microposts feed showing the same results.
I don't know how to make the second feed showing the other pages of microposts.
Can someone help me with this?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not everyone here has looked into Michael Hartl Tutorials. I suppose you should post the real problem with necessary code before they fire you with negative valuations here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're displaying the same instance variable `@microposts` which is a single page of microposts.  You would need a different instance variable for the separate (second) page.

So where you did...

```
@microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

You should also do...

```
@microposts_second = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page] + 1)
```

Now, that's likely to fail if params[:page] is undefined, but hopefully you've learned enough ruby and rails by now to handle that.

In any case, now you have a new collection and you can render it where needed...

```
<%= render @microposts_second %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Michael Hartl Tutorials are more detailed in teaching how to program.. Ruby on Rails. Follow the instruction and understand the paradigm to be able to deal with other tasks relating to Ruby on Rails.

Nevertheless, @SteveTurczyn has given you the best answer to your question.